# SwiftUI Update Preview in .onDrag

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want to update my previews foreground color when dragging an object over a possible DropArea. Unfortunately this does not work:

```
@EnvironmentObject var stateHandler: StateHandler

var preview: ObjectPreview

var body: some View {
    VStack() {
        
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 140)
        
    }
    
    .onDrag {
        return NSItemProvider(object: preview.id as NSString)
    } preview: {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 18)
                    .frame(width: 100, height: 140)
                    .background(stateHandler.showItemSlot ? .green : .black)
    }
    
}
```

The StateHandler is an Environment Object and has has a property:

```
@Published var showItemSlot = true
```

And I checked several times if this value gets changed correctly. What is the problem here?

Comment: Try changing `@EnvironmentObject` to `@StateObject`

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work with StateObject either

Comment: Preview is a preview, it is not dynamic view - it is constructed only once before drag, actually the same as NSItemProvider.

Comment: So there is no way to do this in general?

Comment: You could change the color of the receiving area instead.